# Class constructor using other object

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

So I have the following code which works nicely:

```
CMyClass& CMyClass::operator=(DWORD rhs) 

...

CMyClass exc;
exc = GetLastError();
```

And it does everything I expect it to (call the stuff inside the `=` operator.)
I was wondering how to get it so that I can instead write it like the following:

```
CMyClass exc = GetLastError();
```

I tried using the above and it doesn't call the `=` operator functionality, instead just leaving me with a class where just the default constructor has been called.

Thanks

Comment: Write a converting constructor, `CMyClass(DWORD rhs);`. Then you can even get rid of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor is required.

```
CMyClass(DWORD rhs)
```

Or explicit

```
explicit CMyClass(DWORD rhs)
```

**Be warned**, the implicit constructor allows this to compile;

```
CMyClass exc = GetLastError();
```

But it also participates in compiler generated implicit constructions and conversions. It is generally better to have to be explicit and write;

```
CMyClass exc ( GetLastError() );
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Could you please clarify what you mean by `it also participates in compiler generated implicit constructions and conversions`

Comment: Basically, if another type say, `class ABC` has an type conversion to `DWORD` (`operator DWORD();`), then this would also compile; `CMyClass exc = abc;` where `abc` is an instance of `ABC`. Or worse, if `CMyClass` was an argument to a function `void Func(CMyClass)`, then this would compile `Func(abc)`

Comment: @Luke, See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/3747990) for some more detail on explicit. The first answer basically has the same example as I gave you. The second answer has some more reasons... Best advice is to generally (by default) add the explicit, unless it is required to not be there.